# C++ Linked List Pointer to Struct Crashing

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, linked-list

When I call the default constructor for my class LinkedList I attempt to assign values to the head node of the linked list before any other operations occur. I have isolate the error, via debugging, to the instructions in the default constructor. As soon as

```
    head -> next = NULL;
    head -> RUID = 0;
    head -> studentName = "No Student in Head";
```

are called the program crashes. This occurs when I call the default constructor in main. 
Here is my class declaration and my struct declaration along with the default constructor:

```
struct Node
{
    string studentName;
    int RUID;
    Node* next;
};

class LinkedList
{
private:

    // Initialize length of list 
    int listLength;

public:
    // Head of the list, which points to no data yet
    Node *head;
    LinkedList();
    bool insertNode(Node* newNode, int position);
    int generateRUID(); 

};


LinkedList::LinkedList()
{

    head -> next = NULL;
    head -> RUID = 0;
    head -> studentName = "No Student in Head";

    listLength = 0; 
}
```

I believe this all of the relevant code to this issue. If someone could shed light on this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: `head` must be initialized before all of the others.  It's an empty reference at the start of `LinkedList::LinkedList`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LinkedList::head` is a `Node*`, not a `Node` and you don't initialize it, so the object (binary, in-memory) representation is undefined and is therefore dangerous to dereference.

Change your `LinkedList` to explicitly initialize the `head` member. I recommend storing it by-value (as `Node`) rather than as a heap-allocated value (`Node*`) for simplicitly, unless you know you'll need to reparent nodes.

Using `Node*`:

```
LinkedList::LinkedList() :
    head( Node() ),
    listLength( 0 )
{
    this->head->next = nullptr;
    this->head->RUID = 0;
    this->head->studentName = "No Student in Head";
}
```